# Synchronize two listviews scroll moving

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

How can I synchronize the scrolling of two listviews in a C# Windows form application.

**Example:**
When `listview2` moves up, `listview1` also moves up.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197335/Synchronized-ListBox-objects-or-how-to-scroll-2-Li

**Introduction to the project:**

> Couple of days ago I had a task where I must synchronize two
>   ListBox objects. I have found out, that the ListBox object doesn't have
>   any property which allow to accomplish this. After a few hours of
>   googling I found code of class that inherited from ListBox class. Here
>   is the code of that class:

Comment: [You should include at least a short explanation of the article you linked to.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/130186)

Comment: I do not need WPF. I need windowsform application.